# Vlookup to find occurrence of substring withing larger string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

In column1 I have:

```
London, United KingdomRetail
ItalyConsumer Goods
London, United KingdomManagement Consulting
United KingdomManagement Consulting
Warsaw, Masovian District, PolandLogistics and Supply Chain
PolandInternet
Cologne Area, GermanyWholesale
London, United KingdomFood & Beverages
```

and in column 2:

```
Netherlands
Switzerland
Turkey
Estonia
Greece
United Kingdom
Spain
Belgium
Slovak Republic area
Poland
Hungary 
Italy
Germany
```

My question is: If one of the countries in column 2 appears anywhere in column 1, I want to display it in column 3.  Only one country can appear in column 1.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: See below answer. Let me know if need any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the given ranges I would suggest something like this: (in C1 and copy down)

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$13,A1))),INDEX($B$1:$B$13,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$13,A1)),ROW($B$1:$B$13)))),"")
```

> This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all spaces after commas.
2. Split column one into multiple columns using text to columns then do this:

   =VLOOKUP(A1,C:E,1,FALSE)

You should end up with this (this #N/As are the column with the vLookup):

```
Netherlands          | #N/A | London                              | United KingdomRetail                |
Switzerland          | #N/A | ItalyConsumer Goods                 |                                     |
Turkey               | #N/A | London                              | United KingdomManagement Consulting |
Estonia              | #N/A | United KingdomManagement Consulting |                                     |
Greece               | #N/A | Warsaw                              | Masovian District                   | PolandLogistics and Supply Chain
United Kingdom       | #N/A | PolandInternet                      |                                     |
Spain                | #N/A | Cologne Area                        | GermanyWholesale                    |
Belgium              | #N/A | London                              | United KingdomFood & Beverages      |
Slovak Republic area | #N/A |                                     |                                     |
Poland               | #N/A |                                     |                                     |
Hungary              | #N/A |                                     |                                     |
Italy                | #N/A |                                     |                                     |
Germany              | #N/A |                                     |                                     |
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in `Column 3`

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$13,"*"&B1&"*")=1,B1,"")
```

If you want as a list without blank cells then use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$13,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$13,"*"&$B$1:$B$13&"*")=1,ROW($B$1:$B$13)),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")
```

As it is a array formula, Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.

[image]